# Sorting Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I need to create a sorting algorithm that will sort cards based on pairs, so for example, if you have a 4JJQQ, it should sort QQJJ4.  I have tried many different ways but I seems to have trouble getting the order right.  I basically have a array of cards, containing that hand.

Comment: Please show us what you tried.

Comment: any sorting algorithm (correctly implemented) will have all the pairs next to each other.

Comment: Basically any sorting algo will work as long as you ensure correctness. You say it needs to sort pairs. What happens if there are three? You need to be more specific.

Comment: Not if it is sorted from lowest rank to highest and looks like this.  This is where I appears to struggle the most, 334JJ.  I continually get error messages no matter what I do. It needs to be re sorted as follows, JJ334.  I am on my phone right now but when I get to a computer I will post my code.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is still a bit unclear to me. So I'll make a few assumptions and you can correct me if I am wrong.

If your main problem is to basically compare literals like J and numerals like 4, then [**Counting Sort**](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Counting_sort) is your solution.

*What it is*: It is a sorting algo applied in situations where the possible values being sorted are limited. You create a table of all the possible values, in a sweep, count all the occurrences of each literal updating the same in the respective row in the table. Then all you must do is to use this to sort the original array in whichever order of preference suits you.

*Advantage*: Counting sort is a faster algorithm (takes O(n) time on average) than other generic algos like Merge and Quicksort. If you do have limited possible values then I say you use it.

Now comes the part of sorting it in "pairs" which is something I don't quite understand. 
Can you please tell what the expected answers are for the following test cases *"JJQJ4"* and *"JQ329"*?

Typical Counting sort can sort these as *QJJJ4* and *QJ932* (No concept of pairs here)

If your answer pattern is ***[Pairs][Singular]*** each sorted in decreasing order,
you only need to modify counting sort such that it populates even number of cards first. If the available cards remaining for any literal is 1 or 0, it populates them in the end. That way, the answer to my test cases will be

*JJQJ4* and *QJ923*.

Also both of your test cases seem to fit as well.

---

Alternative:

You mention that you want to skip having to compare both literals when it is clear that they are a pair. Might I suggest using some tree-like storage of literals. So, the idea would be to have a central player node with 2 children. Left Child would store occurrences of pairs while the Right one will store the singular ones.

The storage of literals will be done in a binary tree fashion. The insertion of literals would be modified.

When you get 45JJQ,

1) Input: 4 . Process: store 4 as rChld of player node

2) Input: 5 . Process: store 5 as rChld of 4

3) Input: J . Process: store J as rChld of 5

4) Input: J . Process: Since another J is present, 5->rChld:NULL. J is stored as lChld of player node (again, in binary tree fashion, ie, if there is already a literal present in the lChld [Two Pairs] then the J would be stored as that literals left or right child based on whether it is larger or smaller).

5) Input: Q . Process: store Q as rChld of 5

To compare two hands, you first search the highest card in pairs (the rightmost child having no children). You can also count the number of pairs easily. In a general binary tree you would have required a BFS or DFS. But since you can only have a maximum of 2 pairs, you can do that trivially. If the lChld is null, search again for the high card in the rChild with singular cards.

Note: If you indeed are making a game similar to poker, you might also want stuff like 3 of a kind. That can be accommodated in the nodes by storing a "weight" in the left children of the player node. That is, if J occurs twice, weight is 2, if it occurs thrice, weight is 3 and so on. A better way than weights might be to use [binomial heaps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_heap).

Comment: Don't think that is what I am looking for.  What I need is for my hand to be sorted with pairs first, and then single cards trailing high to low, so if I have a 45JJQ, which is how I sort the hand initially, i need it to resort it as such, JJQ54.  The reason is I need to compare hands of one pair, and in order to do that simply, i need to be able to compare the 1 index of J, if it is the same jump right to the third of Q, and verify who has the largest high card.

Comment: I understand that you are making a kind of poker game. I still feel that the above algorithm fits with what you want to do. Counting sort, as the name suggests, counts the number of occurrences of each literal in the array and stores that number. So, in 45JJQ, the count would be: 4: 1 ; 5: 1 ; J:2 ; Q: 1 ; (all others):0. Now, you overwrite the original array filling items with literals occurring >=2 times times. Deduct 2 from the count each time you store a pair until 1 or 0 remains.  Thus, J goes in the beginning. JJ _ _ _. Now,   since only single occurrences remain, put them in order:JJQ54

Answer (score 1):

If TYPE = {A,K,Q,J,A,10..2} *(Java's `enum` perhaps)*
where A > K > Q > J > 10 > ... > 2

Then, this would do it:

```
class Card implements Comparable<Card> {
  public TYPE ty;
  public Card(TYPE t) {
    ty = t;
  }
  public int compareTo(Card card) {
    return card.ty - ty; //you should rewrite this according to [1] rules
  }
}
```

Sorting:

```
Collections.sort(listOfCards); where listOfCards is a List<Card>.
```

[1] http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=10